# angular 4 how to how default div open

Tags: angular

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 modalbx_r no-padding">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 mt20">
                            <h3 class="text-left margin_bottom10 colorred margin_top0 ">Create Free Account</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 formInnerTitle">
                                        Register as
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 radio-blue-gap margin_top10 form-check">
                                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" [(checked)]="checked" [(ngModel)]="content" value="student"  >
                                        <label for="type1"> Student</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 radio-blue-gap margin_top10 form-check">
                                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="type2" [(ngModel)]="content" value="admin">
                                        <label for="type2"> Admin</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <form>
                            <div id="student" *ngIf="content == 'student'">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user inuser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control inputdes">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar inuser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Date of Birth" class="form-control inputdes">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope inuser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control inputdes">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone inuser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone no." class="form-control inputdes">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="admin" *ngIf="content == 'admin'">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user inuser" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <input type="text"  placeholder="Institute Name" class="form-control inputdes">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="dblock text-right mt20">
                                <a routerLink="/login"  class="pull-left colorred">Already have an account ? Login</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn_custm">Submit</button>
                            </span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to bind initial value on component load

```
content= 'student';
checked;
```

Also no need to bind with `checked` once you bind your value using `ngModel` so just remove this piece of code

```
[(checked)]="checked"
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-erbbzp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)